# Why is my conversion from varchar to bigint not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to convert from varchar to bigint, but keep getting

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

This is my syntax:

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))) 
END
```

This is part of the json value im taking the substring from:

```
{
         "lat": "52.650000",
         "lon": "5.730000",
         "name": "NAGELE",
         "cmt": "PROV: FLEVOLAND, INW: -",
         "desc": "PROV: FLEVOLAND, INW: -",
         "sym": "Medium City"
      },
      {
         "lat": "52.670000",
         "lon": "5.600000",
         "name": "URK",
         "cmt": "PROV: FLEVOLAND, INW: 16489",
         "desc": "PROV: FLEVOLAND, INW: 16489",
         "sym": "Medium City"
      },
```

So when INW: is '-', I want to insert null
when INW: is for example 16489 I want to insert this value (column is a bigint)

I have also tried it like this:

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) AS bigint) 
END
```

This is my loop for the JSON objects:

```
begin
            declare @_StateProvinceID int = (NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequences].[StateProvinceID])
            Insert into [Application].[StateProvinces] (StateProvinceID,StateProvinceCode,StateProvinceName,CountryID,SalesTerritory)
            values(@_StateProvinceID,UPPER(SUBSTRING (@StateProvince, 1, 2)),@StateProvince,@_CountryID,@_SalesTerritory)

            declare @_InnerJson VARCHAR(MAX) = @json
            DECLARE @wpt VARCHAR(MAX);
            SET @wpt = JSON_QUERY(@_InnerJson, '$.wpt');

            ;with cte_a as (
            SELECT UPPER(SUBSTRING (@StateProvince, 1, 2))[StateProvinceCode],@StateProvince [StateProvince],* FROM  
            OPENJSON ( @wpt )  
            WITH (name varchar(max) '$.name',lat varchar(max) '$.lat',lon varchar(max) '$.lon', descr varchar(max) '$.desc'))

            Insert Into [Application].[Cities] (StateProvinceID,CityName,Location,LatestRecordedPopulation)
            select @_StateProvinceID,a.name,geography::Point(lat, lon, 4326),
                (CASE (SELECT SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))) WHEN '-' THEN NULL ELSE (SELECT SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))) END)
            from cte_a a
        End
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this working?

Comment: Try to `SELECT` the substring first, and see what you get

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to provide [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Comment: the length of the substring doesn't look correct IMO. `LEN(descr)`

Comment: descr is what i get from this 
WITH (name varchar(max) '$.name',lat varchar(max) '$.lat',lon varchar(max) '$.lon', descr varchar(max) '$.desc'))

Comment: @Pac0 is correct, you substring from `charindex` to the end of the string (actually beyond, but sql server is very helpful there), which includes a lot of other data from the first `INW:`

Comment: In the sample given, which value do you want returned? I suspect `16489`, in which case your substring gets a whole lot more complicated. And what if there are multiple values for `'INW:'`?

Comment: I believe sql server 2017 has JSON support

Comment: I insert each object, but if INW is '-', i want to insert null in that column. else i want to insert that number. So theres always only one INW

Comment: So in the sample given you want `NULL`?

Comment: Ive added a little more code. maybe now it gets a little clearer what i want. I want to either insert null, or the number given. so in the sample i dont just want NULL

Comment: Try this: `CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, 1)` Are you sure there aren't any trailing spaces anywhere?

Comment: @shawnt00 This still gives me the same error

Comment: When I insert it in a varchar column I get the correct values. its just when the value is a number, the conversion to bigint does not work for the bigint column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ***positive*** that this bit works...

```
SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))
```

Then wrap it in this...

```
CAST(
    NULLIF(
        SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)),
        '-'
    )
    AS BIGINT
)
```

Just be very certain that your original snippet always gives what you want first. Especially that it never gives unexpected spaces, etc.

***Edit:***

As this isn't working I can only conclude that your substring is Not always returning what you expect.

Please show ***both*** the input strings (`descr`) ***and*** the results of the following...  (As an edit to your question.)

```
'>' + SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) + '<'
```

Comment: I'm 100% certain the substring gives back the correct value. I have checked that multiple times by inserting it in a different column. It has no trailing spaces etc. 
But with this I still get the same error

Comment: Then your tests are not robust.  Your code is returning AT LEAST one value that doesn't conform to your expectations.  Insert the values of your substring (without CASE or NULLIF or CAST) into the VARCHAR column, but prefix and suffix with a marker and show us the result in your question.

Comment: @marcel I have to go, if you update your question with the example input from `descr`, I'm sure someone will help you. This is why you should strip your problem down to Only the parts that are the problem, and supply example data with which people can reproduce your problem in their own environment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @marcel - In absence of a reply, here's proof of it working.  Proof where you can change the example data, and reproduce for yourself what I saw...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd11a457eded29c87d53439c9646a27a

Comment: @marcel - Has this or the other answer helped? I notice you haven't upvoted or accepted either answer, nor responded to comments.  Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are sure that you are passing the correct values to your cast/convert function, but you are getting:

```
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

In such cases, the most easier thing to do is to use [TRY_CONVERT](http://l-server-ver15) function. Something like this:

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE TRY_CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))) 
END
```

It will give you two things:

- first, your issue will be solved, as if the input of the function cannot be casted to `bigint` it will give you `NULL`
- second, you can isolate `NULL` values and see is there a record different from `-` that your validation miss and potentially yields the error

Answer (score -1):

As you are focusing on the sql part to find what is the wrong I'm also trying to help you fixing the sql...

You provided here

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr)) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, LEN(descr))) 
END
```

Here substring is not what you are expecting that's why it can't convert that to bigint.
Your substring logic actually returning a string like my local simulation as you see in the following screenshot -
[image]

Now see why it can't convert this to bigint.

Fix would be to control the substring length correctly.
If you know the number is 5 character length then you sql can be rewritten as

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, 1) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, 5)) 
END
```

If the length of the number is not known the query would be like this

```
CASE SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, 1) 
WHEN '-' THEN NULL 
ELSE CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(descr, CHARINDEX('INW: ', descr) + 5, CHARINDEX('",', @someString,CHARINDEX('INW: ', @someString)) - CHARINDEX('INW: ', @someString) - 5))) 
END
```

Hopefully you understand the issue and way to solve it in your actual context.

Comment: The CTE that precedes this line of code opens the json and extracts the `$.desc` value. This means that the input you're using is not representative.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I tried to show you where is your problem and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not the OP. And I'm saying that the input would NOT include the `"desc": ""` portion of the string, `OPENJSON() ` would have parsed that away. The value in `descr` (which is where it would be after parsing the json in the cte) would be `PROV: FLEVOLAND, INW: 16489`